# How to Access Private Subnet EC2 with site to site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-vpc

If I have an AWS VPC with a private and public subnet. The public subnet has 1 EC2 instance and the private subnet has 1 EC2 instance as well. If I do a site to site VPN to my VPC from my work location. Can I access my private subnet EC2 instance via ssh using the private ip? Or do I have to do a Bastian host from my public subnet to access my private subnet EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to ssh to an e2 instance from your on-premise/work location. You need to configure routing from your work location to reach to the ec2 instance IP. Once that is in place and your security groups allows the incoming connection, then you should be good.

Comment: So just to confirm you are saying yes to ssh into my private subnet EC2 instance, correct? I know you can with public subnet EC2 instance just want to know about private subnet.  Thanks

Comment: Yes for private instances, as you will create an a VPSSEC tunnel extending your AWS architecture with work location network.

Comment: You need to add static routes in the site to site VPN connection. These static routes are nothing but the list of IP range that can be routed to the VPC. Also enable the routing propagation in subnet